# Syntastic stops working with a Python distribution

Tags: vim, python-mode, syntastic

I installed a scientific Python distro called Anaconda. Now, my Vim setup complains. I have python-mode installed as a vim plugin, and when I try to save a Python file it runs a syntax check (syntastic). However, this now returns an error.

```
syntastic: error: checker python/python returned abnormal status 2
```

I'm running Python 2.7.7 and vim 7.4. Vim can find the Python installation, as `has('python')` returns 1. Everything else works fine.

What is wrong with syntastic?

Comment: Anaconda-related questions are spreading like wildfire. Don't they have a forum or issue tracker where they can support Vim users?

Comment: I do not feel this problem is unique to Anaconda. This has been the case with all Python distributions I've used, but this is my first post related to the problem.